# How can I avoid the "Low Light!" warning with Samsung S1050 compact camera in Night mode?

Tags: focus, low-light, night, compact-cameras, darkness

I am wanting to take photos in dark conditions using the Night scene mode.  For example, a carved Halloween pumpkin in the dark with a candle in it.  However, I get the "Low Light!" warning message and bleep when focusing, even though the Night scene mode is selected.  How can I take good photos at night with this camera, whilst still maintaining focus and not blurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, here are a few things that help in your situation. I'm not sure which features are available for the Samsung S1050, but if you search your **User Manual** for the *italicized* terms below, you should be able to determine which features your camera offers.

- Use a tripod to eliminate camera shake and allow *slower shutter speeds*.
- *Focus manually* if the amount of light present is not enough to allow the camera's auto focus to work.
- Use *exposure compensation*, *spot metering*, or *manual exposure* so the camera doesn't try to render all of that black background as medium grey.